# Make universal color adjustments to MacOS

Tags: macos, display, applications, preferences, color

Does anyone know of an application that would allow me to make universal color adjustments to the OS? This would mean being able to adjust saturation, black points, white points, or even ideally apply a LUT (Look Up Table) to everything displayed on my Mac. For those of you that are video production savvy, this would be like a much simpler version of DaVinci Resolve but for everything on screen. I know it's possible because applications like FLux have control over the universal color temperature.